# Best lubricant for trailer hinges

Tags: lubrication, trailer

I bought a small cage trailer without a roof about a year ago -- used but in good condition. What is the best lubricant for the hinges of the trailer cage door? (Perhaps graphite or white lithium grease?)

The two hinges are positioned vertically on the left side of the cage door. Each hinge consists of a solid cylindrical peg inside a hollow cylinder, which is open at both ends and powder coated on the outside.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What hinges are you talking about? There are several different types of hinges which could be involved. I know you described them, but that doesn't exactly say which ones they are ...

Comment: A picture would be very helpful for this question.

Comment: Hi @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've updated the description above. It's the two hinges on the left side of the cage door.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for the outside cage door, use some high pressure grease like you'd use for wheel bearings. Any type will do, even white lithium if you have it. Coat the pins liberally and you shouldn't see any issues with it. Reapply as needed. It seems you may be overthinking this a bit. The main purpose is to keep moisture out. By doing so you'll prevent rust buildup and the door should swing quite freely.